# Map an Entity with its EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an application handling multiple EntityManager and I wanna map each entity with its entityManager. How I can map these entities?

One point to consider: I have one EntityManagerFactory and with that factory I create many EntityManagers.Then, I create a new EntityManager per user log in. What i need is to identify the entities related to each EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, if you class is annonated properly it will look be something like:

```
<persistence-unit name="EntityManager1" transaction-type="...">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.somepackage.ClassOne</class>
    <class>org.somepackage.CassTwo</class>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="EntityManager2" transaction-type="...">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.somepackage.ClassThree</class>
    <class>org.somepackage.CassFour</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

However, if you want to map same class to Two EntityManagers pointing to different databses, and having different Table/Column names, then annotations wont help. If thats the class you will have to map atleast Table using xml (and may wish to map other using annotations). xml mappings override annotations.

We had similar scenario where we had to map same entities to two different schema. We mapped same entity to two different tables using two xmls instead of mapping to one with annotations and other with xml, so as to avoid any confusions and/or ambiguities.

Comment: Sorry if I miss leaded you with my question. I have one EntityManagerFactory and with that factory I create many EntityManagers.Then, I create a new EntityManager per user log in. What i need is to identify the entities related to each EntityManager

Comment: You dont need to create EntityManager per user logging into your system and then keep track of entityManagers. The best way to manage this is to use Spring to inject EntityManager in you persistence Classes whenever one is required.